# SQL Evaluate formula stored in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to evaluate a string formula/expression stored in a column? (SQL Server 2014).

Example:

```
TABLE:
ID | Formula
1  | IIF(2<3,'A','B')
2  | IIF(3<4,'C','D')
3  | IIF(5<1,'E','F')
```

Query:

```
SELECT ID, Eval(Formula)
```

Output:

```
1 | A
2 | C
3 | F
```

Comment: It is not possible without Dynamic SQL, which also would have to be executed dynamically for every row because the formula is row specific.  If the formula is column specific (calculated column) then it is a bit easier but still not ideal or suggested practice

Comment: And is a bad idea to start with....\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Dynamic SQL, but REALLY not recommended.  Just in case you REALLY have to...

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Formula varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'IIF(2<3,''A'',''B'')'),
(2,'IIF(3<4,''C'',''D'')'),
(3,'IIF(5<1,''E'',''F'')')

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '>>>'

Select @SQL = Replace(@SQL + concat(' Union All Select ID=',ID,',Value=',Formula),'>>> Union All','')
 From  @YourTable

Exec (@SQL)
```

Returns

```
ID  Value
1   A
2   C
3   F
```

Comment: Thanks John. I realize this is probably not the best way, I have some pretty complex requirements for a system I am building. Just exploring possibilities. Thanks again for the feedback!

Comment: @NateTheGreat Understood.  I've done such things in the past, my only concern is Invalid SQL.  I too would like to see an EVAL() function in SQL.